# Mail sent with Symfony2 never delivered

Tags: php, email, symfony

I work with Symfony2, up to date (2.4.1). I send an email with Swifmailer, but it never delivered.

Symfony's logs say the email is sent. I tried with memory and file spooling. With the file spooling when I execute **swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev**, it says "Processing default mailer... 1 emails sent". So everything is supposed to work. The config is ok (no delivery_address defined for dev or other way to catch mail while developing).

My SysAdmin says there is no problem on the serverside. The others SF2 host on the same server (other Virtual host) are sending mail fine. So I tried to place my app on a supposed working other virtual host, but no way, emails don't arrived. I begin to think it's an issue with the last version of Symfony (my others app are on 2.4.0). I tried to create a new symfony app, from zero, and I get the same problem. I'm lost. Does somebody have a similar problem? Or a way to fix it?

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('noreply@domain.com')
    ->setTo('myemail@example.com')
    ->setBody('TEST');

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

PS: When I send an email with mail() function of PHP, it works.

Comment: have you checked spam folder?

Comment: Come on dude, I'm not so stupid :D No, nothing in spam...

Comment: Swiftmailer doesn't perform delivery, it just sends the message to a mail server's delivery queue, so you need to check the logs for the mail server to see if it ever got received.

Comment: @Zulian can you show us the code u use to send the mail?

Comment: here's the code : `$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
         ->setSubject('Hello Email')
         ->setFrom('noreply@domain.com')
         ->setTo('myemail@example.com')
         ->setBody('TEST')
     ;
     $this->get('mailer')->send($message);`

Comment: I had similar issue in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995847/swiftmailer-successfully-sends-but-no-mail-received check if it is the same for You maybe.

Comment: @Gustek OP says that `mail()` works fine. In your case `mail()` wouldn't be working as well.

Comment: Yes I can send with `mail()` (I just tested again) ! Does mail() function use the same way to send the email ? Actually, I'm about to cry : I tried to set the vendors of an other app sf2 (working fine, nd on this server too), but the mail is never arrived...

Comment: I tried to run the config.php to see any problem. I got 1 major problem : "Add "phar" to suhosin.executor.include.whitelist in php.ini*.". Could this problem cause error to send mail ? (I precise I 'm not the server administrator)

Comment: I have some news : it works when I set `'www-data@www.mydomain.com'` in the setFrom. But it's a little ugly... However, if I send with mail function : `mail("client@example.com",'subject','message',"From: noreply@mydomain.com\n");` I get the mail and the sender is 'noreply@mydomain.com', so the server seems to allow to put the sender we want.But it doesn't work with Swifmailer...
Any idea ? Thanks for your help...